# reloadData for TableView not loading cellForRowAtIndexPath or row count

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, reloaddata

I am trying (in vain) to reload tableView in `MasterViewController` from another View Controller `SitesViewController`. I use this code in the `SitesViewController`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [[self tableView].indexPathForSelectedRow row];

    //NSArray *appcell = [sitesMenu objectForKey:@"Table"];

    NSLog(@"AppCell %@", sitesMenu);

    NSDictionary *entry = [sitesMenu objectAtIndex:row];



    self.siteid = [entry objectForKey:@"SITEID"];

    NSLog(@" sample SiteView %@", siteid);

    NDSClassMasterViewController *detailControllerTwo = [[NDSClassMasterViewController alloc] init];
    detailControllerTwo.globalid = siteid;

    NSLog(@"message %@", detailControllerTwo.globalid);



    [detailControllerTwo fetchTweets];



    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [detailControllerTwo.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"%@", detailControllerTwo);
    });
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}
```

and this code for the method I am calling:

```
- (void)fetchTweets
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{



        NSString *siteurl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://adhoc.nyxtek.co.za/spfjsonws/default2.aspx?siteid=%@", globalid];
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString: siteurl]];

        NSError* error;

        menuItems = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];

        NSLog(@"%@", menuItems);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

I have even added the reload code into the SiteViewController didSelectRow method.

I have read that I should add a property for it and synthesize but I have tried that but not sure how to add a property for UITableView to reference to the existing one.

The fetchTweets code runs, but the TableView doesn't reload.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

EDIT

This is the TableView code where I load the items in the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //NSString *name = [[[menuItems objectForKey:@"Table"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"MENUID"];
    NSDictionary *tweet = [[menuItems objectForKey:@"Table"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSLog(@"%@", tweet);

    NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"MENUDESC"];
    NSString *name = [tweet objectForKey:@"MENUDESC"];
    NSLog(@"TEST 1%@", text);
    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", name];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exposing the table view via a property, why not simply write a function within the view controller that contains the code that would reload the data?

E.G. instead of:

```
    [detailControllerTwo.tableView reloadData];
```

Declare a method in your MasterViewController that looks like:

```
- (void) updateTable
{
    // tableView is declared as an IBOutlet
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

and then you can call that with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [detailControllerTwo updateTable];
    NSLog(@"%@", detailControllerTwo);
});
```

Comment: Still somehow not working, i've added:  IBOutlet UITableView *tableView; to the MasterViewController.h file. I've also logged the code step by step in debug and every line runs in the method except the reload doesn't update the table.

Comment: add this line before the "`reloadData`":  "`if (tableView == NULL) NSLog( @"why is my table view outlet not connected?" );`".  I have a feeling your outlet isn't connected, even within the master view controller.

Comment: I added it and I got the printout - I am not entirely sure now if I added the outlet correctly. I added it by dragging the TableView into the MasterViewController.h file as IBOutlet UITableView *tableView; , is that the way?

Comment: I changed it to self.tableView and then I don't get the printout but still no reload of only the cellForRowIndexPath (number of rows in section is working now though).